# Need Preset that will make mp4 H264 with MP3 Encoding

Tags: mp3, h.264, ubuntu-16.04, video-editing, mlt

Working With KDEnlive 16.12 on a Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 i7-920 System
From what I understand KDEnlive 16.12 uses the Melt Framework to compose the video presets.

Am trying to define a preset for 
MP4 H264 1920x1080 29.97 with MP3 audio instead of AAC
Would Like Video 3800 Kbps
Audio 192Kbps

The presets I have defined so far creates mp4 files with AAC audio only.  The source video does have AAC sound.

When I use Handbrake for my video that does not need editing work I turn off passthru and use mp3 encoding.  This produces a mp4 H264 file with MP3 encoding.  I tried looking for the command line that results from the combination of parameters that have been set in the Handbrake GUI, but no joy. Are the parameters used by Handbrake the same as those used by KDEnlive/Melt ?  If not, what Framework does Handbrake use?

Note: Encoding with mp3 in Handbrake does not result in the distortion that is produced when AAC is used in Handbrake. The AAC audio that KDEnlive/Melt produces is not as bad as the AAC audio produced by handbrake. Would like to try encoding mp3 in KDEnlive to see if the distortion I am hearing when encoding with AAC can be eliminated altogether by using mp3 encoding in KEDnlive/Melt.

Thanks

Comment: Necrobumping, needed the same thing. I am on arch, I needed to install `lame`, on Ubuntu, it's probably `libmp3lame` (multiverse). The preset is just `f=mp4 movflags=+faststart vcodec=libx264 progressive=1 g=15 bf=2 crf=%quality acodec=libmp3lame ab=%audiobitrate+'k'`

Answer (score 1):

Reading on https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/

```
acodec
title: Audio codec 
description: Use "list" to see the list of audio codecs.
type: 
readonly: no
required: no
default: mp2
```

[ Blank Line inserted for formatting purposes ]

```
$ melt -query "audio_codecs"
---
audio_codecs:
  - libmp3lame
  - libtwolame
```

in an existing preset the acodec parameter

```
acodec=libmp3lame ab=%audiobitrate+'k'
```

replaced the original acodec parameter

```
acodec=aac ab=%audiobitrate+'k'
```

The result was an H264 mp4 file with MP3 audio encoding instead of AAC encoding.